# How to implement an interface on a NavigationDrawerActivity?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am currently implementing an interface in a blank activity without any problem but then when I  have to shift to another activity, for example an activity that already implements something like a navigational drawer I am confused as to how to implement my interface. for example for the interface below

```
public interface TabsListener {
    void onTabAdded();
    void onTabRemoved();
}
```

I would implement it this way on a blank activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TabsListener {
```

but then again for an Navigation drawer activity which already implements a Listener do I have to include my interface as a sub class or can it be done from the main method ?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigatioinItemSelectedListener {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java you can extend only one class but you can implement all the interfaces you want.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Interface1, Interface2 {

    private Interface1 mListener1;
    private Interface2 mListener2;
}
```

If you want to create a new interface that extends functionalities of another one, could be nice extend directly the base interface:

```
Interface1 {
      public void method1();
}

Interface2 extends Interface1 {
      public void method2();
}

class MyClass implements Interface2 {

      @Override public void method1(){}
      @Override public void method2(){}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement by separated by comma(,).

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigatioinItemSelectedListener,TabsListener {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an interface with multiple interfaces:

```
public interface MyInterface{
    interface Interface1{
        void methodX();
    }
    interface Interface2{
        void methodY();
    }
    interface Interface3{
        void methodZ();
    }       
}
```

Then in your activity:

```
public class MyActivity
        extends AppCompatActivity
        implements MyInterface.Interface1,
        MyInterface.Interface2{

    @Override
    public void methodX() {
    //some fun code
    }

    @Override
    public void methodY() {
    //some fun code
    }
}
```